# Webform, validate field against another field of submitted data

Tags: 7, webforms

I have built an event registration page.
I have a registration web form that people fill out. When they submit the form  they receive a registration code.
If they are registering additional people they need to enter that registration code in a field so that all the registrations are linked together and are searchable by the registration managers.

I want to reduce the possibility of people entering a wrong registration code by having the "Primary Registration Code" field validate against the registration code field of existing submissions.

The registration code field is generated by the webform serial module and is a hidden field on the form.

Any ideas how I can make this validation work?